# ASP.NET MVC/jQuery/AJAX: link fails to work first time, but works second time (after page reloads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Preface**

For this question, I have a **MVC** partial view. The view has a section which displays a list of documents. Each document has a hyperlink: when clicked, the hyperlink takes the user to a second page view displaying additional information.

The link is inside an unordered list:

```
<a style="text-decoration:underline;" onclick="sendToDocketSearch('@currentDocument.DktYear','@currentDocument.DktSequence','@currentDocument.DktSubActionID');">@currentDocument.DktYear.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') - @currentDocument.DktSequence.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, it takes them to a `sendToDocketSearch` javascript function (to prepare to search for the document):

```
var sendToDocketSearch = function (yearOfDocket, sequenceOfDocket, dktSubActionIDOfDocket) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("DocketSearchOnDemand")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ docketYear: yearOfDocket, 
                               docketSequence: sequenceOfDocket,
                               DktSubActionID: dktSubActionIDOfDocket,
                             userIsAuthorized: '@Model.userIsAuthorized' }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });

        submitForm();
    }
```

*Note that the page/view/form is submitted after the following controller method is run:*

```
public ActionResult DocketSearchOnDemand(string docketYear, string docketSequence, decimal DktSubActionID, bool userIsAuthorized, PortalIndexView viewmodel)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("userIsAuthorized", userIsAuthorized);

        string docketSearch = docketYear + "-" + docketSequence;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DocketSearchOnDemand"] = docketSearch;
        if (DktSubActionID > 0)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DktSubActionID"] = DktSubActionID.ToString();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchingCustomID"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DktSubActionID"] = "1";
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["searchingCustomID"] = false;
        }

        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

The above controller method runs; then, because the form is submitted, the HttpPost action for the page takes place. When running it on my local PC, the link is clicked and the next page is loaded without drama.

**Problem**

The problems start when I upload the code to the dev/test server. I don't know how to use breakpoints while troubleshooting an active website, so I follow along with the browser developer tool to monitor network traffic.

When clicking the link when running the website on my localserver, the process continues:

- the hyperlink takes me to a method where I pass information to be searched
- the page/view/form is submitted
- the controller redirects where I have to go.

When I click the link on the site *and it's on the server*, the first click is completely ignored - network traffic shows that it tries to navigate to the controller via the javascript function above, but the failure happens so fast I can't even take a screenshot of it. The page reloads a second time at this point.

When I click on the same link a second time, it works without fail.

I believe the view/javascript/controller code works because it works the second time (and on subsequent attempts). It just flagrantly fails the first time on the server; after that, the user is fine. I'd like to prevent that "first-time" failure, however, and I'm wondering what the problem could be...

1. **Bad timing**

I may be passing the information too early (or too late for my website/server to process it properly). The page does it correctly the second time, so maybe I'm just "jumping the gun" by not waiting a little longer for page-loading processes to sort themselves out. (Maybe I can fiddle around with the `$(document).ready()` javascript portion of the first page to "delay" allowing people to click a link.)

2. **Code error**

I'll be glad to admit bad code if I'm genuinely messing something up. Maybe it's my javascript function, or maybe it's the code in my controller; at any rate, something is making the first pass of that function call be rejected. Maybe my code is bad because the problem doesn't happen the second time, and I'm getting a false sense of security (i.e. there are problems with my code that the system is willing to forgive after the page has *thoroughly* loaded).

3. **Server problem/miscellaneous**

I'm wondering if I missed something when I uploaded my latest changes, or if I should have contacted my network team in case there are permissions that need to be activated for the site to work smoothly. I'm already in touch with them regarding something else, so I might take advantage of the opportunity today.

There is an alternative in place that could help me prevent this problem from happening, but I want to find out why the "first-time" failure happens. Other similar actions fail the first time on the site, and I'd like to apply the insights from fixing this issue to them.

Thank you for looking at this issue. Have a great day.

Comment: Debugging a live site would be done with logging, you should write to a log file to see what is happening behind the scenes.  This may be a good place to start.  For the JS just log to the console and for your backend code you could always log to the Event Viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm taking a look at online resources right now to implement console logging. It would need to work when the website code is uploaded to the dev/test server; hopefully it will catch inconsistencies or code problems (due to the speed at which the attempted click fails).

Comment: In JS you would simply write inline `console.log(stuff you want to log)` where stuff you want to log is pretty much anything you can think of.  Event Viewer would be using a System defined object that you can find in the msdn documentation.  Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Sure does. I'll jump into the code to see what I can find. What is your recommended console log-viewing tool, and how do you hook it up to a browser?

Comment: Use chromes debugger, just hit F12 while looking at a web page. Helpful link to learn it https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging if you are doing anything web related this is of the highest value to learn.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much for your help. I'm about to debug now.

Comment: One more thing worth mentioning, with the dev tools window you can add and subtract JS while working with a live page. This way you don't have to make local changes and deploy them, simply do what you need to then update your code base when you work out the kinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to call `submitForm();` before your `jQuery.ajax` has finished?  your ajax call is async so it will hit `submitForm();` before it has had time to finish.  should `submitForm();` be in your `success` event instead?

Comment: I tried putting the `submitForm()` javascript function into my `success` event. When I clicked the link which fired that call, it doesn't submit the form. However, your answer brings up an excellent point: *timing appears to be part of the problem.* There's another function I can try which might circumvent the issue; I was just trying to shed light on why it happened at all. (Btw: `submitForm()` is just a quick fn equivalent of `$('form').submit()` for me.)

Comment: your success is probably failing because your ajax call is expecting `json` back but you're returning `View()`

Comment: The problems happened with every jQuery function that also had a `submitForm()` call. I tried using `async: false` and the functions behaved: the `jQuery.ajax` call ran, then my `submitForm()` ran. I can definitely go ahead and check my syntax further... I'll mark your response as my answer. Thank you for your help!